# ImportError: No module named 'Cython'

Tags: python, windows, pip, cython

I'm trying do `from Cython.Build import cythonize` and I get the message `ImportError: No module named 'Cython'`, but I installed the Cython with the comand `pip install Cython`. What's wrong?

Python 3.5
Cython 0.25.2
Windows 8

Comment: What is the output of running `python --version` in your terminal?

Comment: @Brian Python 3.5.0

Comment: If you have multiple python-versions, the most robust way, is to use `python -m pip xxxx`, as described in the duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I reinstalled the Cython with conda and install the Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools and it works fine.

Answer (score 79):

Just directly install from pypi:

```
pip install Cython
```

https://pypi.org/project/Cython/

Answer (score 47):

Use Pip3 command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade cython
```

Comment: I've undone an edit that changed `pip3` -> `pip` since it seems to change the point of this answer. The useful bit of the edit was to suggest (that on some shells) `alias pip=pip3` (for those that want to only type `pip`).

Answer (score 10):

The problem for me was the `pip` version. Running `python -m pip install pip --upgrade` solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can download the the newest Cython release from http://cython.org/ or you can directly download by clicking this link [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/be/08/bb5ffd1c32a951cbc26011ecb8557e59dc7a0a4975f0ad98b2cd7446f7dd/Cython-0.28.1.tar.gz#md5=c549effadb52d90bdcb1affc1e5dbb97) Unpack the tarball or zip file, enter the directory, and then run:

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 3):

I personally ran into this problem when I was trying to set up a new virtual environment. I simply installed Cython with `python -m pip install Cython` and then proceeded to install all the rest of my stuff I needed with `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`.
Once it was done, it actually uninstalled Cython for me...
Why? Heck do I know... I ain't that kind of expert :<

Answer (score 1):

it should be path problem.
go to windows search for python idle
right click idle - open file location
where
right click on python.exe - open file location
if the module not in that location
type cmd and press enter in path
now install module with pip install cython
it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same issue/error message when trying

```
pip install .
```

for a package. Then I tried running

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
python setup.py install
```

in the same environment (cython was already installed and up to date there) and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case  insalling setuptools solves issue

```
pip install setuptools
```