# how to install HDBSCAN modula, python 3.7, windows 10

Tags: python, installation, module, hdbscan

I need to use the HDBSCAN algorithme on my data but the module is not installed. I use python 3.7. I am not very familiar with this kind of tricky installations, please, can anyone give me a clear and understandable instructions how to install HDBSCAN?

- I've downloaded the module from : *https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan#egg=hdbscan*
- I unziped it
- I opened the command prompt in the folder where I saw the **setup.py** file
- I ran the folowing command: `python setup.py install --prefix="C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\py37_v1"` (in one line)

and I get the following error: **"Due to incompatibilities with Python 3.7 hdbscan now"**
**"requires Cython to be installed in order to build it"**
**"Cython not found! Please install cython and try again"**

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56746386/6505847

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 I am on a windows 10 machine .
Do you know if there's an easy script to copie instead of installing?

Answer (score 1):

[Install from Official Github](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan#installing)

Easiest install, if you have Anaconda (thanks to conda-forge which is awesome!):

`conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan`

PyPI install, presuming you have an up to date pip:

`pip install hdbscan`